# 301 Redirect a folder to a single page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a folder on my website that has been superceded and I want to redirect an attempt to access any file in this folder to the current home page.

I have read many questions here but none seem to do exactly this.

I have tried various things in .htaccess but it seems to always append the filename to the redirect address.

```
redirect 301 old/$ www.example.com/index.html
redirect 301 old/ www.example.com/index.html
redirect 301 ^old/ www.example.com/index.html
```

I have seen various mentions of RewriteRule. Do I need to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/old/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/index.html [L]
```

OR from root .htaccess use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old(/.*)?$ http://www.example.com/index.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Ignore the above - I didn't realise there is a time limit on editing comments.  I got it to work but only if I put the full URL, not just /index.html ??